# RDLC - display list of objects on rdlc report

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I would like to display list of objects in my report contain in dataset.

Example. MyDataSet has:

```
List<StudentAddress> {get; set;}
```

So how could I able to display StudentAddress in my report which is a report.

Thanks..

Comment: convert your list<> to DataTable, with the data storing as Row record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.

The solution I found is the following one [Reporting against a domain model](http://codebetter.com/petervanooijen/2009/07/01/reporting-against-a-domain-model/).

From the documentation I found ssrs does not support a nested list of object. like what you are looking for.

What is possible is to use a nested object let's say instead of the list you have

```
public Address StudentAddress {get; set;}
```

for this you have to decalre the classes as Serializable. Here you have another link that explains that

[ReportViewer - object datasource, nested objects return](http://wraithnath.blogspot.ch/2011/04/reportviewer-object-datasource-nested.html)

I hope the nested list feature will be implemented soon.